# Adding a action listener in java for a counter

Tags: java, python, swing, button, actionlistener

I am a fairly new user with programming in Java with about a week and a bit experience, as of before I have been using python for about 3 years but thought to give java a try.
I have been trying to develop my skills by creating small projects and applications and am now creating a small GUI counter.

I have achieved creating the GUI with 2 buttons and a label and have tested the maths behind the application but I am struggling to work out how the ActionListener works as it feels a lot different to python when making a button have a action.

This is My Code;

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI{
  //This creates a frame or panel to contain things
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  //Maths To The Counter
  int Counter = 0;
  System.out.println(Counter);
  Counter =+ 1;
  System.out.println(Counter);

  //Creating The Frame
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

  //Creating The Label
  JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Counter: ");
  panel.add(label3); 

  //Button Which should have a funtion to add and display the number
  JButton button = new JButton("Click Here.");
  panel.add(button);

  //Button to reset the counter
  JButton buttonReset = new JButton("Reset Counter.");
  panel.add(buttonReset);

  //Set Size Of Window
  frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
  //Set Starting Position to centre
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  //Setting a default close action
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  //Set Title
  frame.setTitle("Counter");
  //Disable Resize
  frame.setResizable(false);
  //Setting if its visible
  frame.setVisible(true);
  //Fits frame to fit everything
  frame.pack();


  }



}
    enter code here
```

I know that in python a action is in a function so that has been my logic to this problem however I have seen that I need to use the actionlistener instead and I am struggling to get my head around it.

If Someone could show me how this type of action should be implemented it would be great help, I have watch some youtube videos and done a bit of research but im still struggling to understand in my situation how to do it.

For any confussion im sorry, overall my question is how do I add a action to a button in my program that can implement my maths at the start.

As well any feedback on the structure of my code would be welcomed as I am just starting in java and I do know poor structure can lead to mistakes.

Comment: Please see [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

Basically, in the main method I am creating an instance of the class and calling a method to create the gui.

I also created an instance variable as the counter, otherwise you won't be able to update the variable in your action listener.

```
public class Gui {

    private int counter;

    // This creates a frame or panel to contain things
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gui gui = new Gui();
        gui.create();
    }

    private void create() {

        // Creating The Frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        // Creating The Label
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Counter: ");
        panel.add(label3);

        // Button Which should have a funtion to add and display the number
        JButton button = new JButton("Click Here.");
        panel.add(button);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(counter++);
            }
        });

        // Button to reset the counter
        JButton buttonReset = new JButton("Reset Counter.");
        panel.add(buttonReset);

        buttonReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                counter = 0;
            }
        });

        // Set Size Of Window
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        // Set Starting Position to centre
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // Setting a default close action
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Set Title
        frame.setTitle("Counter");
        // Disable Resize
        frame.setResizable(false);
        // Setting if its visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
        // Fits frame to fit everything
      }
  }
```

---

With Lambda expressions, you can simplify your action listeners as follows:

```
button.addActionListener(a -> System.out.println(counter++));
buttonReset.addActionListener(a -> counter = 0);
```

If you want to write more than 1 statement, then you can just put your code in curly brackets:

```
button.addActionListener(a -> {
        System.out.println(counter++);
        System.out.println("doing more stuff...");
});
```

Comment: Thanks That's great help. Cleared Up The Confusion. Im looking to expand my skills in GUIs is there anything you recommend to learn from, any websites, books, or youtube videos.

Comment: You are welcome. This is a pretty good tutorial for `Java Swing` https://www.udemy.com/java-swing-complete/, although I think `JavaFX`  may be more popular these days.

Answer (score 0):

`JButton` has a function called `addActionListener`. You can pass on an action listener by doing this:

```
button.addActionListener(() -> {
    // Do some logic here
});
```

Here, I use a lambda expression as an action listener. Within the lambda expression you can place whatever logic you want to have.

Also note that you can add multiple different action listeners to the same button. In a nutshell, the way the `JButton` interacts with the `ActionListeners` is based on the **observer-pattern**.

Imagine this: When the `JButton` is pressed, it will notify all of it's observers saying "Hey, I have been pressed". Each observer can then independently decide what to do. In case of the `JButton`, all observers are `ActionListeners`. If you add multiple `ActionListeners` then the `JButton` will notify all of them, and as a result all of their `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` functions are executed. In the example above, I used a lambda expression which then by java is interpreted as an `ActionListener`.

Other ways to achieve the exact same functionality are:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Do some logic here
    }
});
```

In the example above, you use an `anonymous class` as an actionlistener.

```
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() {
        JButton button = new JButton("press me");
        button.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
    }

    private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Do some logic here
        }

    }

}
```

In the example above, an inner class is used.

In a nutshell, there is a ton of ways you can make your button have functionality. Above are just a few examples of how to do so.

Does this clarify it a bit more, or do you have some remaining questions?